# TextinputLayout does not display the style correctly if hintEnabled false

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I have TIL for entering phone number. The input should be frame so set style. But I need to disable hint animation, I set `app:hintEnabled="false"` animation work correct, but my border not displayed correctly. Please help

View:
[image: View]

View on focus:
[image: View on focus]

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/phone_text_input"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
                >

                <com.bitnic.loyalitybitnic.widget.FTextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/phone_edit_text_input"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:hint="@string/phone"
                    app:style_font="medium"
                    />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Update:
If I delete `app:hintEnabled="false"` then the view displayed correct
Correct view
[image: Correct view]

Comment: What do you want exactly? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I add new scren what should it look like in the end with app:hintEnabled="false"